Byte code python 3.10.10
I’am dealing with challenge in my study but i didn’t find solution could anyone give me hint :

import re
import string
from types import CodeType
import random

banner = """
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

       "`-:-.   ,-;"`-:-.   ,-;"`-:-.   ,-;"`-:-.   ,-;"`-:-.   ,-;"
           `=`,'=/     `=`,'=/     `=`,'=/     `=`,'=/     `=`,'=/  
             y==/        y==/        y==/        y==/        y==/   
           ,=,-<=`.    ,=,-<=`.    ,=,-<=`.    ,=,-<=`.    ,=,-<=`. 
       _,-'-'   `-=_,-'-'   `-=_,-'-'   `-=_,-'-'   `-=_,-'-'   `-=_

                                HelixScribe
                                   v23.7
                            
                     Copyright Â© 2023 HelixScribe LLC.
                            All rights reserved.

       "`-:-.   ,-;"`-:-.   ,-;"`-:-.   ,-;"`-:-.   ,-;"`-:-.   ,-;"
           `=`,'=/     `=`,'=/     `=`,'=/     `=`,'=/     `=`,'=/  
             y==/        y==/        y==/        y==/        y==/   
           ,=,-<=`.    ,=,-<=`.    ,=,-<=`.    ,=,-<=`.    ,=,-<=`. 
       _,-'-'   `-=_,-'-'   `-=_,-'-'   `-=_,-'-'   `-=_,-'-'   `-=_

"""

header = """/=/   \=\   *-----------------------------------------------------------*
|=|   |=|   |           |              Chromosome                       |
\=\   /=/   | Base Pair |-----------------------------------------------|
 `.\ /,'    |           |   A   |   B   |   C   |   D   |   E   |   F   |
   `\.      |-----------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
"""

bps = """ ,'/ \`.    |     1     |
/=/   \=\   |     2     |
|=|   |=|   |     3     |
\=\   /=/   |     4     |
 `.\ /,'    |     5     |
   ,/'      |     6     |
 ,'/ \`.    |     7     |
/=/   \=\   |     8     |
|=|   |=|   |     9     |
\=\   /=/   |    10     |
 `.\ /,'    |    11     |
   ,/'      |    12     |
 ,'/ \`.    |    13     |
/=/   \=\   |    14     |
|=|   |=|   |    15     |
\=\   /=/   |    16     |
 `.\ /,'    |    17     |
   `\.      |    18     |
 ,'/ \`.    |    19     |
/=/   \=\   |    20     |
|=|   |=|   |    21     |
\=\   /=/   |    22     |
 `.\ /,'    |    23     |
   ,/'      |    24     |
 ,'/ \`.    |    25     |
/=/   \=\   |    26     |
|=|   |=|   |    27     |
\=\   /=/   |    28     |
 `.\ /,'    |    29     |
   `\.      |    30     |""".split("\n")

footer = " ,'/ \`.    *-----------------------------------------------------------*"

print(banner)

genes = "".join([random.choice(string.hexdigits.upper()) for i in range(720)])


def specimen(): pass


def gene_printer():
    global genes
    o = header
    for b in range(30):
        o += bps[b]
        for c in range(6):
            o += " %s-%s |" % (genes[c*30*4+b*4:c*30*4+b*4+2],genes[c*30*4+b*4+2:c*30*4+b*4+4])
        o += "\n"
    o += footer
    print(o)


def gene_editor():
    global genes
    chromosome = input("Please enter the chromosome that you would like to edit (A-F): ").strip().upper()
    print()
    if (chromosome + " ")[0] not in "ABCDEF":
        print("Error. Invalid option.")
        return

    base_pair = input("Please enter the starting base pair that you would like to edit (1-30): ").strip().upper()
    print()
    if not re.fullmatch(r'[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30',base_pair):
        print("Error. Invalid option.")
        return

    chromosome_index = (int(base_pair)-1)*4

    sequence = input("Please enter the new gene sequence: ").upper()
    print()
    sequence = "".join([i for i in sequence if i in string.hexdigits.upper()])

    length = min(30*4-chromosome_index, len(sequence))
    sequence = sequence[:length]

    starting_index = 30 * 4 * (ord(chromosome) - 65) + chromosome_index
    genes = genes[:starting_index] + sequence + genes[starting_index + length:]
    print("Edit successful.")


def test_survivability():
    global genes
    specimen.__code__ = CodeType(0, 0, 0, 2, 32, 67, bytes.fromhex(genes), (None,),
                                 ('chr', 'eval'), ('', ''), '', '', 0, b'', (), ())
    try:
        specimen()
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        return False


while True:
    print("---------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print()
    print("Select option:")
    print(" 1. View genes")
    print(" 2. Edit genes")
    print(" 3. Test survivability")
    print()
    option = input("Enter number: ").strip()
    print()
    if option == "1":
        gene_printer()
    elif option == "2":
        gene_editor()


can't read the code due to its formatting, but typically you'd want to start by importing the dis module, and then using it on the desired code object. It looks like CodeType is being used to create a code object from the bytecode in genes. That'd probably be a good object to disassemble.

Your post misses a question. Effectively it is only code. Please edit it and include a verbose description of the problem you have.
